# Setting background-image with knockout: Works in chrome but not other browsers

Tags: css, google-chrome, knockout.js

I'm using knockout to set the background image on some divs:

```
<div class="values" data-bind="foreach: values" >
  <div class="cvsection" data-bind="style: {'background-image': backgroundimg}" style="background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size:100%;background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center bottom;">

    <!-- Stuff inside the div -->   
  </div>
</div>
```

Where in my viewmodel, each value() has a property like:

```
backgroundimg: 'url(i/img.jpg)'
```

The background images show up as expected in Chrome and IE9, but not Firefox 15 or IE8. I don't see any javascript errors in the console or anything.

Do you think this is a problem with knockout, or some other CSS issue? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Could you make a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) to demonstrate the problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suppose your snippet should be

```
<div class="values" data-bind="foreach: values" >
  <div class="cvsection" data-bind="style: {backgroundImage: backgroundimg}" style="background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size:100%;background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center bottom;">

    <!-- Stuff inside the div -->   
  </div>
</div>
```

*'background-image'* was changed to *backgroundImage*

According to [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/style-binding.html):

> If you want to apply a font-weight or text-decoration style, or any
>   other style whose name isn’t a legal JavaScript identifier (e.g.,
>   because it contains a hyphen), you must use the JavaScript name for
>   that style.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look [here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/style-binding.html), when it says:

> Note: Applying styles whose names aren’t legal JavaScript variable names
>
> If you want to apply a font-weight or text-decoration style, or any
> other style whose name isn’t a legal JavaScript identifier (e.g.,
> because it contains a hyphen), you must use the JavaScript name for
> that style. For example,
>
> Don’t write { font-weight: someValue }; do write { fontWeight:
> someValue }
>
> Don’t write { text-decoration: someValue }; do write { textDecoration:
> someValue }

So that, if you want to apply the css rule "background-image", you have to write "backgroundImage" in the knockout's *style binding*.

Docs always do the trick ;)